# Incorrect JavaScript-library version is loaded from Maven/WebJars

Tags: java, scala, maven, sbt, webjars

In my build.sbt I have the following:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
   "org.webjars.npm" % "moment" % "2.19.3"
)
```

However, in the project some other dependency seems to have a dependency on latest moment version, and thus moment 2.19.4 is loaded through org.webjars.npm.moment:2.19.4.jar. So if I try to load the dependency like this

```
@routes.WebJarAssets.at("moment/2.19.3/min/moment.min")
```

It now gives 404, because that version doesn't exist in the project.

How can I determine what library is using moment:latest or moment:2.19.4 and how I can explicitly force to use 2.19.3? Or what might be the proper solution to this, as the build breaks every time there is a new version pushed of moment.js.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this sbt plugin to see your dependency graph: https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph

But you should be using the `webjars-play` lib to make those references version agnostic: http://www.webjars.org/documentation#play2